# How do you sort a collection by something other than its own properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) on adding basic sorting/filtering to an ASP.NET MVC application.

The trouble is, I don't actually want to sort by the model's properties, but rather `string`s derived from the model's `int` properties.

The `ExceptionModel` below has a `ClientID`, `PatientID`, and `PhysicianID` which link to an entry in another `DbSet`. I need to sort by that entry's name.

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder)
{
    ViewBag.ClientSortParam = System.String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "client_desc" : "";
    ViewBag.PatientSortParam = sortOrder == "Patient" ? "patient_desc" : "Patient"; // If sorting by Patient (ascending), flip to patient_desc, otherwise remain
    ViewBag.PhysicianSortParam = sortOrder == "Physician" ? "physician_desc" : "Physician";
    IQueryable<ExceptionModel> exceptions = from e in db.Exceptions
                                            select e; // Select all in table
    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "client_desc": // Default is Client ascending, at the bottom
            exceptions = exceptions.OrderByDescending(e => db.Clients.Find(e.ClientID).Name);
            break;

        case "Patient":
            exceptions = exceptions.OrderBy(e => db.Patients.Find(e.PatientID).Name);
            break;
        case "patient_desc":
            exceptions = exceptions.OrderByDescending(e => db.Patients.Find(e.PatientID).Name);
            break;

        case "Physician":
            exceptions = exceptions.OrderBy(e => db.Physicians.Find(e.PhysicianID).Name);
            break;
        case "physician_desc":
            exceptions = exceptions.OrderByDescending(e => db.Physicians.Find(e.PhysicianID).Name);
            break;

        default:
            exceptions = exceptions.OrderBy(e => db.Clients.Find(e.ClientID).Name);
            break;
    }

    return View(exceptions.ToList());
}
```

My current `exceptions.OrderBy(e => db.Patients.Find(e.PatientID).Name)` attempt throws this runtime exception:

> System.ArgumentException: Method 'EDB.Models.ClientModel Find(System.Object[])' declared on type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[EDB.Models.ClientModel]' cannot be called with instance of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[EDB.Models.ClientModel]'

Edit:

I'm told I should be using Entity navigation properties. Right now I just have something like this:

```
public class ExceptionModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int PatientID { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public int PhysicianID { get; set; }
}

public class PatientModel // Never need to go from Patient to Exception, so I typically access this with db.Patients.Find(exception.PatientID)
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class ClientModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<int> PhysicianIDs { get; set; } // One client has many physicians
    public string PhysicianStore { get { /* parse list to string */ } set { /* parse string to list and store in PhysicianIDs */ } }
}

public class PhysicianModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; } // Each physician maps to one client
}
```

I do not understand what I'm supposed to change to remedy this problem.

Comment: Create navigation properties and `OrderBy(e => e.Patient.Name)` and so on.

Comment: You are trying to create a SQL statement from your linq statements. If you really want to sort your list like this, you need first to perform the SQL statement... So I guess you could first retrieve a list of exceptions... and then you can use your order.

Comment: List<ExceptionModel> exceptions = (from e in db.Exceptions
                                            select e).ToList();
But this is not really the most performant way to do :)

Comment: @LaurentLequenne Okay, that works, but could you further explain why? And perhaps a faster alternative? All I did was add `ToList()` to everything: the statement you mentioned and the right side of all the assignment operations. I don't see what's being accomplished here.

Comment: Roughly you should create navigation Properties as said by @CodeCaster      :) The way you implement can differ depending what EF framework you are using, if you are using the model builder or not ... a start could be : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: @LaurentLequenne So now I get to redo all my models? Sweet. How do I save ICollection in the database? Currently I have my list convert to a string that gets saved.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591620(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: @LaurentLequenne What's wrong with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44598960)?

Answer (score 0):

Laurent Lequenne's comment is accurate.  You're using Entity.  You're trying to sort by values that are calculated client-side.  Entity cannot translate this calculation to SQL Server statements, so it's throwing an exception.

The comment about it not being performant was true, too.  You could use `ToList` to retrieve the results and continue processing with no exceptions thrown, but it will get ugly with large result sets; you'd want to push that sort of processing to a sproc.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the related data, you should use a join that can be translated. I assumed you don't need the `Exceptions` that don't have a matching `Clients`, etc. to sort on so I used an inner join. If you do, you can use a left outer join instead.

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder) {
    ViewBag.ClientSortParam = System.String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "client_desc" : "";
    ViewBag.PatientSortParam = sortOrder == "Patient" ? "patient_desc" : "Patient"; // If sorting by Patient (ascending), flip to patient_desc, otherwise remain
    ViewBag.PhysicianSortParam = sortOrder == "Physician" ? "physician_desc" : "Physician";
    IQueryable<ExceptionModel> exceptions = db.Exceptions;

    switch (sortOrder) {
        case "client_desc": // Default is Client ascending, at the bottom
            exceptions = from e in exceptions join c in db.Clients on e.ClientID equals c.ClientID orderby c.Name descending select e;
            break;

        case "Patient":
            exceptions = from e in exceptions join p in db.Patients on e.PatientID equals p.PatientID orderby p.Name select e;
            break;
        case "patient_desc":
            exceptions = from e in exceptions join p in db.Patients on e.PatientID equals p.PatientID orderby p.Name descending select e;
            break;

        case "Physician":
            exceptions = from e in exceptions join p in db.Physicians on e.PhysicianID equals p.PhysicianID orderby p.Name select e;
            break;
        case "physician_desc":
            exceptions = from e in exceptions join p in db.Physicians on e.PhysicianID equals p.PhysicianID orderby p.Name descending select e;
            break;

        default:
            exceptions = from e in exceptions join c in db.Clients on e.ClientID equals c.ClientID orderby c.Name descending select e;
            break;
    }

    return View(exceptions.ToList());
}
```

Comment: So if I'm understanding this right, what I have doesn't work because I'm trying to perform operations on stuff that hasn't actually been run yet, and this instead adds more operations that get evaluated when `View` is called? That probably doesn't make any sense, but I tried... And all `Exception`s have a matching `Client`, etc.

Comment: Your code didn't run because it used `Find` which can not be translated to SQL for the database. The `join` operation is fully supported by EF/LINQ to SQL and can be translated to execute on the database. The translation/execution occurs when `ToList` is called. If you had added `ToList` before the `OrderBy` to pull the records from the database and then run the `Find` on the web server, that would also have worked.

Comment: Is there a preferable option in terms of efficiency?

Comment: That is hard to say. It depends on the amount of data you are returning, the amount of data to be joined and the speed and load on your database server. The general rule of thumb is it is better to offload to the database server and minimize queries - your code would make multiple queries to the database server to pull back the records and then to find the match per record, then sort. That is unlikely to be better than having the database server do it all in one query.

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Actually, what's wrong with [this](https://hastebin.com/olecupojuy.php)?

Comment: Isn't that your original code that is in your question? As I said earlier: Your code didn't run because it used `Find` which will not be translated to SQL for the database.

Comment: No, that's not my original, but it is a very slight edit. Instead of trying to queue a bunch of SQL and then execute it with `View(~.ToList())`, I just made a list to begin with, then changed that list.

Comment: Not what your link showed me. `IEnumerable<ExceptionModel> exceptions = db.Exceptions;`, `exceptions = exceptions.OrderByDescending(e => db.Clients.Find(e.ClientID).Name);`, `return View(exceptions.ToList());`, nut nothing wrong with doing it the way you said except you will be searching the SQL server once for every member of `db.Exceptions` for the matching record, so lots of SQL server queries = slow and inefficient.

Comment: Does that code not do what I said? Not sure how to be more specific about your code not working. The sorting doesn't work. Nothing happens. Didn't debug it yet though, I guess I was hoping you'd go "oh, I forgot to dot that i".

Comment: I know it's only been a couple days, but I would much appreciate a response.